# How to deal with AJAX redirects when doing Rails integration story tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, redirect, integration-testing

I'm trying to figure out how to run integration tests that are storybased and where AJAX redirects appear during the 'story'.

Simple login example: I login to the website using

```
def user.logs_in(email, pwd)
    get root_path

    assert_response :success
    assert_template 'index'

    post :post, session_path, :email => email, :pwd => pwd

    assert_response :redirect
    assert_redirect_to backend_path

    follow_redirect!

    assert_response :success
    assert_template 'index'
    assert session[:user_id]
  end
```

Unfortunately the login process is AJAX based and insted of a 301-redirect it returns

```
document.location.href = "<%= backend_path >";
```

which gives back a 200-code meaning that

```
assert_response :redirect
```

fails.

How can i handle AJAX redirects in my integration tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no redirect, of course you won't be able to (successfully) test for it. So instead test for what you are doing: You want the response to be a `200` and the body to be a Javascript snippet. Or just use `assert_template`, too.

If you want to test if your Javascript-Login-Button actually evals the js body and how the browser reacts to that you would have to use something like Selenium.